# Converting string "MM/yyyy" to date in sql query

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table with `salaryMonth` field containing month and year ["04/2017"] as string. I want to get data between specific time span I have used following queries but they fail and give me error cannot convert date or time from character string.

`SELECT salaryMonth FROM viewSalary WHERE (CONVERT(date, '1/' + salaryMonth) > '2/22/2017')`

also

`SELECT salaryMonth FROM viewSalary WHERE (CONVERT(date, '1/' + salaryMonth) >= CONVERT(date, '2/22/2017'))`

I also swapped the month and day part but still no luck.

Comment: Is is mysql or sql-server?.. It can't be both

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server?

Comment: sorry its sql server

Comment: what is your sql-server's version?

Comment: @TriV Sql server 2012. working in VS 2013 Creating Dataset

Comment: You're doing convert(date,"104/2017") that's never going to work!

Comment: @JeffUK its typo.  i was doing `convert(date,'1/'+salaryMonth)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT salaryMonth 
FROM viewSalary 
WHERE (CONVERT(date, '01/' + salaryMonth, 103) >= CONVERT(date, '02/22/2017', 103)
```

Comment: This is for `dd/MM/yyyy`. The style parameter `101` means American style date - dd/MM/yyyy....

Comment: no problem. you and @HenryLu both helped me i fixed my problem. now i dont know which answer to accept. please help me which one should i select . both of u really did great.

Comment: i think you replied first so your answer. thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

as per @ATC's answer, TSQL allows you to specify a style when converting to/from a datetime. this is that 101 in the last parameter in the convert statement

```
CONVERT(date, '01/' + salaryMonth, 101)
```

for a full list of available formats see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

in your case, for dd/MM/yyyy i believe the code is 103

```
CONVERT(date, '01/' + salaryMonth, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
SELECT salaryMonth FROM viewSalary 
WHERE CAST('01/'+salaryMonth AS date) > CAST('2/22/2017' AS DATE)
```

Comment: i have month+year in field. i am concatenating days with it.. please tell me how to convert formate dd/MM/yyyy not MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic SQL you need to convert your value to a valid SQL date, with format: `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
DECLARE @datestring AS NVARCHAR(10) = '04/2017';

SELECT  CAST(RIGHT(@datestring, 4) + '-' + 
             LEFT(@datestring, 2) + '-01' AS DATE) AS DateVal;
-- produces: 2017-04-01
```

Adding to your SQL:

```
SELECT salaryMonth 
FROM viewSalary 
WHERE CAST(RIGHT(salaryMonth , 4) + '-' + 
             LEFT(salaryMonth , 2) + '-01' AS DATE) > '2017-02-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2012+ you could use [datefromparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) like this

```
SELECT salaryMonth 
FROM viewSalary 
WHERE datefromparts(RIGHT(salaryMonth,4), LEFT(salaryMonth,2),1) >= Datefromparts(2017,2,22)
```